# List Index Is Out of Range And I Don't Know Why

Tags: python, list, for-loop, indexing

So this is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\python\cloud.py", line 593, in <module>
    inventory()
  File "E:\python\cloud.py", line 297, in inventory
    print("Weapon Attack Damage: ", c.weaponAttack[i])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

These are the only parts of the code that have the "weaponAttack" function in it. I honestly don't see why it is giving me this error.

```
 class Cloud:
    def __init__(self):
        self.weaponAttack = list()
        self.sp = 0
        self.armor = list()
        self.armorReduction = list()
        self.weapon = list()
        self.money = 0
        self.lvl = 0
        self.exp = 0
        self.mexp = 100
        self.attackPower = 0
        self.hp = 100
        self.mhp = 100
        self.name = "Cloud"
c = Cloud()
armors = ["No Armor","Belice Armor","Yoron's Armor","Andrew's Custom Armor","Zeus' Armor"]
armorReduce = [.0, .025, .05, .10, .15]
c.armor.append(armors[0])
c.armorReduction.append(armorReduce[0])
w = random.randint(0, 10)
weapons = ["The sword of wizdom","The sword of kindness", "the sword of power", "the sword of elctricity", "the sword of fire", "the sword of wind", "the sword of ice", "the sword of self appreciation", "the sword of love", "the earth sword", "the sword of the universe"]
weaponAttack = [12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22]
c.weapon.append(weapons[w])
c.weapon.append(weaponAttack[w])
print("You have recieved the ", weapons[w])
print("")
print("It does ", weaponAttack[w]," attack power!")
print("")

    for i in range(0, len(c.weapon)):
        print(i)
        print("Weapon: ", c.weapon[i])
        print("Weapon Attack Damage: ", c.weaponAttack[i])
        print("")
```

Although, this is the rest of the code, but before you read it, I'm warning you, it's long. Either way, I'm pretty sure that those lines of code up there are the problem.

```
import random
import time
import sys
def asky():
    ask = input("Would you like to check you player stats and inventory or go to the next battle? Say inventory for inventory or say next for the next battle: ")
    if "inventory" in ask:
        inventory()
    elif "next" in ask:
        user()
def Type(t):
    t = list(t)
    for a in t:
        sys.stdout.write(a)
        time.sleep(.02)
class Cloud:
    def __init__(self):
        self.weaponAttack = list()
        self.sp = 0
        self.armor = list()
        self.armorReduction = list()
        self.weapon = list()
        self.money = 0
        self.lvl = 0
        self.exp = 0
        self.mexp = 100
        self.attackPower = 0
        self.hp = 100
        self.mhp = 100
        self.name = "Cloud"
c = Cloud()
armors = ["No Armor","Belice Armor","Yoron's Armor","Andrew's Custom Armor","Zeus' Armor"]
armorReduce = [.0, .025, .05, .10, .15]
c.armor.append(armors[0])
c.armorReduction.append(armorReduce[0])
w = random.randint(0, 10)
weapons = ["The sword of wizdom","The sword of kindness", "the sword of power", "the sword of elctricity", "the sword of fire", "the sword of wind", "the sword of ice", "the sword of self appreciation", "the sword of love", "the earth sword", "the sword of the universe"]
weaponAttack = [12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22]
c.weapon.append(weapons[w])
c.weapon.append(weaponAttack[w])
print("You have recieved the ", weapons[w])
print("")
print("It does ", weaponAttack[w]," attack power!")
print("")
class Soldier:
    def __init__(self):
        dmg = random.randint(5,20)
        self.lvl = 0
        self.attackPower = dmg
        self.hp = 100
        self.mhp = 100
        self.name = "Soldier"
s = Soldier()
def enemy():
    ad = random.randint(0,2)
    if ad >= 1: #Attack
        Type("Soldier attacks!")
        print("")
        Type("Cloud Health: ")
        print(c.hp)
        Type("Enemy Health: ")
        print(s.hp)
        hm = random.randint(0, 2)
        if hm == 0:
            Type("Miss!")
            print("")
        elif hm > 0:
            crit = random.randint(0,10)
            if crit == 0:
                print("CRITICAL HIT!")
                crithit = int((s.attackPower) * (.5))
                c.hp = c.hp - (s.attackPower + crithit)
            elif crit >= 1:
                c.hp = c.hp - s.attackPower
            Type("Cloud Health: ")
            print(c.hp)
            Type("Enemy Health: ")
            print(s.hp)
        if c.hp <= 0:
            adds = s.mhp - s.hp
            s.hp = s.hp + adds
            Type("GAME OVER")
            print("")
            Type("You Lost!")
            print("")
        elif s.hp <= 0:
            adds = s.mhp - s.hp
            s.hp = s.hp + adds
            Type("GAME OVER")
            print("")
            Type("You Won!")
            print("")
            Type("You recieved 100 crystals to spend at the shop!")
            print("")
            c.money = c.money + 100
            asky()
            c.exp = c.exp + 100
        else:
            user()
    elif ad == 0:#Defend
        Type("Soldier Defends!")
        print("")
        Type("Cloud Health: ")
        print(c.hp)
        Type("Enemy Health: ")
        print(s.hp)
        if s.hp == s.mhp:
            print("")
        elif s.hp > (s.mhp - 15) and s.hp < s.mhp:
            add = s.mhp - s.hp
            s.hp = add + s.hp
            Type("Cloud Health: ")
            print(c.hp)
            Type("Enemy Health: ")
            print(s.hp)
        elif s.hp < (s.mhp - 15):
            s.hp = s.hp + 15
            Type("Cloud Health: ")
            print(c.hp)
            Type("Enemy Health: ")
            print(s.hp)
        if c.hp <= 0:
            adds = s.mhp - s.hp
            s.hp = s.hp + adds
            Type("GAME OVER")
            print("")
            Type("You Lost!")
            print("")
        elif s.hp <= 0:
            adds = s.mhp - s.hp
            s.hp = s.hp + adds
            Type("GAME OVER")
            print("")
            Type("You Won!")
            print("")
            Type("You recieved 100 crystals to spend at the shop!")
            print("")
            c.money = c.money + 100
            asky()
            c.exp = c.exp + 100
        else:
            user()
def user():
    User = input("attack or defend? ")
    if "attack" in User:#attack
        Type("Cloud attacks!")
        print("")
        Type("Cloud Health: ")
        print(c.hp)
        Type("Enemy Health: ")
        print(s.hp)
        hm = random.randint(0,4)
        if hm == 0:
            Type("Miss!")
            print("")
        elif hm > 0:
            crit = random.randint(0,7)
            if crit == 0:
                print("CRITICAL HIT!")
                crithit = int((c.weaponAttack[0]) * (.5))
                s.hp = s.hp - (c.weaponAttack[0] + crithit)
            elif crit >= 1:
                s.hp = s.hp - c.weaponAttack[0]
            Type("Cloud Health: ")
            print(c.hp)
            Type("Enemy Health: ")
            print(s.hp)
        if c.hp <= 0:
            adds = s.mhp - s.hp
            s.hp = s.hp + adds
            Type("GAME OVER")
            print("")
            Type("You Lost!")
            print("")
        elif s.hp <= 0:
            adds = s.mhp - s.hp
            s.hp = s.hp + adds
            Type("GAME OVER")
            print("")
            Type("You Won!")
            print("")
            Type("You recieved 100 crystals to spend at the shop!")
            print("")
            c.money = c.money + 100
            c.exp = c.exp + 100
            asky()
        else:
            enemy()
    elif "defend" in User:#defend
        Type("Cloud Heals!")
        print("")
        Type("Cloud Health: ")
        print(c.hp)
        Type("Enemy Health: ")
        print(s.hp)
        if c.hp == c.mhp:
            Type("You are at the maximum amount of health. Cannot add more health.")
            print("")
        elif c.hp > (c.mhp - 15) and c.hp < c.mhp:
            add = c.mhp - c.hp
            c.hp = add + c.hp
            Type("Cloud Health: ")
            print(c.hp)
            Type("Enemy Health: ")
            print(s.hp)
        elif c.hp <= (c.mhp - 15):
            c.hp = c.hp + 15
            Type("Cloud Health: ")
            print(c.hp)
            Type("Enemy Health: ")
            print(s.hp)
        if c.hp <= 0:
            adds = s.mhp - s.hp
            s.hp = s.hp + adds
            Type("GAME OVER")
            print("")
            Type("You Lost!")
            print("")
        elif s.hp <= 0:
            adds = s.mhp - s.hp
            s.hp = s.hp + adds
            Type("Congratulations!")
            print("")
            Type("You Won!")
            print("")
            Type("You recieved 100 crystals to spend at the shop!")
            print("")
            c.money = c.money + 100
            c.exp = c.exp + 100
            asky()
        else:
            enemy()
    else:
        Type("The option you have entered is not in the game database. Please try again")
        print("")
        user()
def inventory():
    if c.exp == c.mexp:
        print("LEVEL UP!")
        c.exp = 0
        adde = int((c.mexp) * (.5))
        c.mexp = c.mexp + adde
        c.sp = c.sp + 1
        c.lvl = c.lvl + 1
        if c.lvl > s.lvl:
            s.lvl = s.lvl + 1
        print("Level: ", c.lvl)
        nextlvl = c.lvl + 1
        print("Experience: ", c.exp, "/", c.mexp, "level", nextlvl)
        print("Amount of Skill Points:", c.sp)
        for i in range(0, len(c.weapon)):
            print(i)
            print("Weapon: ", c.weapon[i])
            print("Weapon Attack Damage: ", c.weaponAttack[i])
            print("")
        for j in range(0, len(c.armor)):
            print("Armor: ", c.armor[j])
            print("Armor Damage Reduction: ", c.armorReduction[j])
            print("")
        print("Amount of Crystals: ", c.money)
        print("")
        print("")
        print("Stats:")
        print("Maximum Health: ", c.mhp)
        print("Current Health: ", c.hp)
        print("Your Name: ", c.name)
        print("")
        sn = input("To heal yourself, you need to go to the shop. Say, *shop* to go to the shop, say  *name* to change your name, say, *next* to fight another battle, say, *level* to use your skill point(s), or say, *help* for help: ")
        if "name" in sn:
            c.name = input("Enter Your name here: ")
            print("Success! Your name has been changed to ", c.name)
            inventory()
        elif "next" in sn:
            Type("3")
            print("")
            Type("2")
            print("")
            Type("1")
            print("")
            Type("FIGHT!")
            print("")
            user()
        elif "help" in sn:
            Type("The goal of this game is to fight all the enemies, kill the miniboss, and       finally, kill the boss! each time you kill an enemy you gain *crystals*,        currency which you can use to buy weapons, armor, and health. You can spend     these *crystals* at the shop. To go to the shop, just say *shop* when you are in your inventory. Although, each time you defeat an enemy, they get harder to    defeat. Once you level up, you gain one skill point. This skill point is then   used while in your inventory by saying the word *level*. You can use your skill point(s) to upgrade your stats, such as, your maximum health, and your attack   power.")
            print("")
            inventory()
        elif "shop" in sn:
            shop()
        elif "level" in sn:
            skills()
    else:
        print("Level: ", c.lvl)
        nextlvl = c.lvl + 1
        print("Experience: ", c.exp, "/", c.mexp, "level", nextlvl)
        print("Amount of Skill Points:", c.sp)
        for i in range(0, len(c.weapon)):
            print("Weapon:", c.weapon[i])
            print("Weapon Attack Damage: ", c.weaponAttack[i])
            print("")
        for i in range(0, len(c.armor)):
            print("Armor: ", c.armor[i])
            print("Armor Damage Reduction: ", c.armorReduction[i])
            print("")
        print("Amount of Crystals: ", c.money)
        print("")
        print("")
        print("Stats:")
        print("Maximum Health: ", c.mhp)
        print("Current Health: ", c.hp)
        print("Attack Power: ", c.attackPower)
        print("Your Name: ", c.name)
        print("")
        sn = input("To heal yourself, you need to go to the shop. Say, *shop* to go to the shop, say  *name* to change your name, say, *next* to fight another battle, say, *level* to use your skill point(s), or say, *help* for help: ")
        if "name" in sn:
            c.name = input("Enter Your name here: ")
            print("Success! Your name has been changed to ", c.name)
            inventory()
        elif "next" in sn:
            Type("3")
            print("")
            Type("2")
            print("")
            Type("1")
            print("")
            Type("FIGHT!")
            print("")
            user()
        elif "help" in sn:
            Type("The goal of this game is to fight all the enemies, kill the miniboss, and       finally, kill the boss! each time you kill an enemy you gain *crystals*,        currency which you can use to buy weapons, armor, and health. You can spend     these *crystals* at the shop. To go to the shop, just say *shop* when you are in your inventory. Although, each time you defeat an enemy, they get harder to    defeat. Once you level up, you gain one skill point. This skill point is then   used while in your inventory by saying the word *level*. You can use your skill point(s) to upgrade your stats, such as, your maximum health, and your attack   power.")
            print("")
            inventory()
        elif "shop" in sn:
            shop()
        elif "level" in sn:
            skills()
def skills():
    print("You have ", c.sp, "skill points to use.")
    print("")
    print("Upgrade attack power *press the number 1*")
    print("")
    print("Upgrade maximum health *press the number 2*")
    print("")
    skill = input("Enter the number of the skill you wish to upgrade, or say, cancel, to go back to your inventory screen.")
    if "1" in skill:
        sure = input("Are you sure you want to upgrade your character attack power in return for 1 skill point? *yes or no*")
        if "yes" in sure:
            c.sp = c.sp - 1
            addsap = c.attackPower * .01
            c.attackPower = c.attackPower + addsap
        if "no" in sure:
            skills()
    elif "2" in skill:
        sure = input("Are you sure you want to upgrade your maximum health in return for 1 skill point? *yes or no*")
        if "yes" in sure:
            c.sp = c.sp - 1
            c.mhp = c.mhp + 30
        if "no" in sure:
            skills()
    elif "cancel" in skill:
        inventory()
    else:
        Type("The word or number you have entered is invalid. Please try again.")
        print("")
        skills()
def shop():
    print("Welcome to Andrew's Blacksmith! Here you will find all the weapons, armor, and health you need, to defeat the horrid beast who goes by the name of Murlor! ")
    print("")
    print("Who's Murlor? *To ask this question, type in the number 1*")
    print("")
    print("Can you heal me? *To ask this question, type in the number 2*")
    print("")
    print("What weapons do you have? *To ask this question, type in the number 3*")
    print("")
    print("Got any armor? *To ask this question, type in the number 4*")
    print("")
    ask1 = input("Enter desired number here or say, cancel, to go back to your inventory screen. ")
    if "1" in ask1:
        def murlor():
            Type("Murlor is a devil-like creature that lives deep among the caves of Bricegate. He has been terrorising the people of this village for centuries.")
            print("")
            print("What is Bricegate? *To choose this option, type in the number 1*")
            print("")
            print("Got any more information about this village? *To choose this option, type in the number 2*")
            print("")
            print("Thank you! *To choose this option, type in the number 3*")
            ask3 = input("Enter desired number here, or say, cancel, to go back to the main shop screen. ")
            if "1" in ask3:
                Type("That's the name of this town.")
                murlor()
            elif "2" in ask3:
                def askquest1():
                    quest1 = input("Well I DO know that there's this secret underground dungeon. It's VERY dangerous but it comes with a hug reward. If you ever concider it, could you get my lucky axe? I dropped it down a hole leading to the dungeon and i was too afraid to get it back. *If you accept the quest, say yes, if you want to go back, say, no.*")
                    if "yes" in quest1:
                        quest1()
                    elif "no" in quest1:
                        murlor()
                    else:
                        Type("The option you have selected is not valid. Please try again")
                        print("")
                        askquest1()
            elif "3" in ask3:
                shop()
            else:
                Type("The number or word you have entered is invalid. please try again.")
                print("")
    elif "2" in ask1:
        def heal():
            Type("Sure! That'll be 30 crystals.")
            ask2 = input(" *say, okay, to confirm the purchase or say, no, to cancel the pruchase*")
            if "okay" in ask2:
                if c.money < 30:
                    Type("I'm sorry sir, but you don't have enough crystals to buy this.")
                    print("")
                    shop()
                elif c.money >= 30:
                    c.money = c.money - 30
                    Type("30 crystals has been removed from your inventory.")
                    print("")
                    addn = c.mhp - c.hp
                    c.hp = c.hp + addn
                    Type("You have been healed!")
                    print("")
                    shop()
            elif "no" in ask2:
                shop()
            else:
                Type("The option you have chosen is invalid. Please try again")
                print("")
                heal()
    elif "3" in ask1:
        def swords():
            print("Swords: ")
            print("The Belice Sword: *Type 1 for this sword*")
            print("Damage: 18")
            print("Cost: 70 crystals")
            print("")
            print("The Sword of A Thousand Truths: *Type 2 for this sword*")
            print("Damage: 28")
            print("Cost: 100 crystals")
            print("")
            print("Spyro's Sword: *Type 3 for this sword*")
            print("Damage: 32")
            print("Cost: 125 crystals")
            print("")
            print("The Sword Of The Athens: *Type 4 for this sword*")
            print("Damage: 36")
            print("Cost: 150 crystals")
            print("")
            print("Coming Soon...")
            sword = input("Enter the sword ID number or say cancel to go back to the main shop screen. You now have ", c.money, "crystals.")
            if "1" in sword:
                if c.money < 70:
                    Type("I'm sorry sir, but you don't have enough crystals to buy this.")
                    print("")
                    swords()
                elif c.money >= 70:
                    c.money = c.money - 70
                    Type("70 crystals has been removed from your inventory.")
                    print("")
                    weapon.append("The Belice Sword")
                    Type("The Belice Sword has been added to your inventory!")
                    print("")
                    swords()
            elif "2" in sword:
                if c.money < 250:
                    Type("I'm sorry sir, but you don't have enough crystals to buy this.")
                    print("")
                    swords()
                elif c.money >= 250:
                    c.money = c.money - 250
                    Type("250 crystals has been removed from your inventory. You now have ", c.money, "crystals.")
                    print("")
                    weapon.append("The Sword Of A Thousand Truths")
                    Type("The Sword Of A Thousand Truths has been added to your inventory!")
                    print("")
                    swords()
            elif "3" in sword:
                if c.money < 525:
                    Type("I'm sorry sir, but you don't have enough crystals to buy this.")
                    print("")
                    swords()
                elif c.money >= 525:
                    c.money = c.money - 525
                    Type("525 crystals has been removed from your inventory. You now have ", c.money, "crystals.")
                    print("")
                    weapon.append("The Spyro's Sword")
                    Type("The Spyro's Sword has been added to your inventory!")
                    print("")
                    swords()
            elif "4" in sword:
                if c.money < 1050:
                    Type("I'm sorry sir, but you don't have enough crystals to buy this.")
                    print("")
                    swords()
                elif c.money >= 1050:
                    c.money = c.money - 1050
                    Type("1050 crystals has been removed from your inventory. You now have ", c.money, "crystals.")
                    print("")
                    weapon.append("The Sword Of The Athens")
                    Type("The Sword Of The Athens has been added to your inventory!")
                    print("")
                    swords()
            elif "cancel" in sword:
                shop()
            else:
                Type("The number or word you have entered is invalid. Please try again.")
                print("")
                swords()
    elif "4" in ask1:
        def armory():
            print("Armor:")
            print("Belice Armor, ID: 1")
            print("Damage Reduction: 2.5%")
            print("Cost: 100 crystals")
            print("")
            print("Yoron's armor, ID: 2")
            print("Damage Reduction: 5%")
            print("Cost: 250 crystals")
            print("")
            print("Andrew's Custom Armor, ID: 3")
            print("Damage Reduction: 10%")
            print("Cost: 500 crystals")
            print("")
            print("Zeus' Armor, ID: 4")
            print("Damage Reduction: 15%")
            print("Cost: 1000 crystals")
            print("")
            print("Coming Soon...")
            print("")
            armor = input("Enter armor ID number, or type, cancel, to go back to the main shop menu.")
            if "1" in armor:
                if c.money < 100:
                    Type("I'm sorry sir, but you don't have enough crystals to buy this.")
                    print("")
                    armory()
                elif c.money >= 100:
                    c.money = c.money - 100
                    Type("100 crystals has been removed from your inventory. You now have ", c.money, "crystals.")
                    print("")
                    weapon.append("Belice Armor")
                    Type("Belice Armor has been added to your inventory!")
                    print("")
                    armory()
            elif "2" in armor:
                if c.money < 250:
                    Type("I'm sorry sir, but you don't have enough crystals to buy this.")
                    print("")
                    armory()
                elif c.money >= 250:
                    c.money = c.money - 250
                    Type("250 crystals has been removed from your inventory. You now have ", c.money, "crystals.")
                    print("")
                    weapon.append("Yoron's Armor")
                    Type("Yoron's Armor has been added to your inventory!")
                    print("")
                    armory()
            elif "3" in armor:
                if c.money < 500:
                    Type("I'm sorry sir, but you don't have enough crystals to buy this.")
                    print("")
                    armory()
                elif c.money >= 500:
                    c.money = c.money - 500
                    Type("500 crystals has been removed from your inventory. You now have ", c.money, "crystals.")
                    print("")
                    weapon.append("Andrew's Custom Armor")
                    Type("Andrew's Custom Armor has been added to your inventory!")
                    print("")
                    armory()
            elif "4" in armor:
                if c.money < 1000:
                    Type("I'm sorry sir, but you don't have enough crystals to buy this.")
                    print("")
                    armory()
                elif c.money >= 1000:
                    c.money = c.money - 1000
                    Type("1000 crystals has been removed from your inventory. You now have ", c.money, "crystals.")
                    print("")
                    weapon.append("Zeus' Armor")
                    Type("Zeus' Armor has been added to your inventory!")
                    print("")
                    armory()
            elif "cancel" in armor:
                shop()
            else:
                Type("The word or number you have entered is invalid. Please try again")
                armory()
    elif "cancel" in ask1:
        inventory()
    else:
        Type("The number or word you have entered is invalid. Please try again.")
        print("")
        shop()
inventory()
```

Comment: Why are you expecting `c.weaponAttack` to have any elements at all?

Comment: Yeah, sorry i honestly didn't see it. I'm really sorry for wasting your time with this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your problem is here:

```
weapons = ["The sword of wizdom","The sword of kindness", "the sword of power", "the sword of elctricity", "the sword of fire", "the sword of wind", "the sword of ice", "the sword of self appreciation", "the sword of love", "the earth sword", "the sword of the universe"]
weaponAttack = [12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22]
c.weapon.append(weapons[w])
c.weapon.append(weaponAttack[w])
```

That last line should probably be:

```
c.weaponAttack.append(weaponAttack[w])
```

Comment: Oh lord I'm really sorry for wasting your time with this silliness..

Comment: he, he.  we all have to get started.  depending on how you run your program, you may be able to use the Python debugger.  roughly:  **import pdb  try: <your code that may fail> except Exception, e:  pdb.set_trace()**.  Sorry for formatting.  Gist is that on an uncaught exception you get a debugger command line and you can do things like **print(c.weaponAttack)** or **vars(c)** .

Comment: Oh that's amazing! How would i make that run though? Do I just import pdb try: put in the code here except exception, e: etc.. and then it'll just run the debugger automatically or do i have to attach it somewhere in my code?